# Can't see email older than 30 days

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Galaxy S4 Active and I cant find emails that are older than 30 days. How do i get them back? I didn't delete them.

Comment: What app? GMail? Email?

Comment: There is a value which can be either in your Setting App, or Mail application for the days to Sync. GKRAEIEC has stated this. If you have any issues please update your question with what application you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in settings for your email account where you select how long to cache email locally. It works on a per label basis so you can store starred emails for longer than inbox (or whatever you like).

Comment: This was a good answer, but for someone who is unsure perhaps provide an example. Something as simple as this may aid your answer: Go to Settings - Mail (May be called Accounts) - Select your Mail Account - Sync and then alter the value here. If you're unable to find this here, go into your Mail application, settings and look for sync. Your answer is correct, however if you go that extra mile you'll be able to improve your answer, better help someone and also get it marked as correct.